# joining table with similar strings

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables both has a column called `rid`.

t1 rid data are in the format of
`/api/v1/services/abc-xyz`
e.g.,
`/api/v1/services/public-controller`

t2 rid data are in the format of
`/api/v1/pods/abc-xyz-<random string>`
e.g.,
`/api/v1/pods/public-controller-74c52bst4`

How can I join these two tables based on the following rule:

```
join t1, t2 when 
t1.rid = `/api/v1/services/abc-xyz` 
t2.rid = `/api/v1/pods/abc-xyz-<random string>`
```

e.g.,
the rows with rid = `/api/v1/services/public-controller` in t1 should join with the rows with rid = `/api/v1/pods/public-controller-74c52bst4` in t2.

Comment: I believe you need to match the string startWith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the pattern is that you want to match the string after "services" with the string after "pods", but in the case of "pods" only until the second "-" is occurring, because then the  starts.

This SQL uses SUBSTR, POSITION and LENGTH to extract abc-xyz based on your pattern for t1.rid:

```
select substr('/api/v1/services/abc-xyz', POSITION( 'services/' IN '/api/v1/services/abc-xyz') + length('services/'))
```

The same SQL can be used to extract abc-xyz-<random_string> out of t2.rid, but adjusted to "pods/". Now you could continue and use STARTSWITH to compare and check whether t2.rid starts with t1.rid.

Final condition:

```
STARTSWITH(substr(t2.rid, POSITION( 'pods/' IN t2.rid) + length('pods/')),substr(t1.rid, POSITION( 'services/' IN t1.rid) + length('services/')))
```

Now there are many things which can go wrong actually, but based on your pattern at least this should to the trick. Also I guess there are more straightforward solutions.

Comment: this solution is not complete. what about the join